# Ubuntu One: Problem while trying to register

Tags: ubuntu

Well this is not really a specific Ubuntu's problem but I only experienced it on Linux Ubuntu so I'll ask it here.
I can't read CAPTCHAs on Ubuntu One's registration window. I tried to read it by a hand magnifier, by asking other people to try reading it, by refreshing it several times in order to find something easier to read and nothing helped! Whatever I enter it returns an error saying wrong CAPTCHA, Any suggestion?!

Comment: This seems to be an acknowledged issue: see [The CAPTCHA challenge in Ubuntu Software Center is much too difficult to solve for a real human being](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/1033598)

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks a lot! Looks like I'm not alone and also it looks like no one in ubuntu centre cares about this!

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu one has been brought down by Canonical.

http://blog.canonical.com/2014/04/02/shutting-down-ubuntu-one-file-services/

Comment: AFAIK only the hosting service ("Ubuntu One File Services") has been discontinued: it should still be possible to create new accounts (for the OpenID SSO service for example)

Comment: I want to participate in reviewing apps (U.S.C.). That's where it asks for UO's account and that's where my problem shows up!